# Subtracting 0x8000 from an int

Tags: c

I am reverse engineering some old C, running under Win95 (yes, in production) appears to have been compiled with a Borland compiler (I don't have the tool chain).

There is a function which does (among other things) something like this:

```
static void unknown(int *value)
{
  int v = *value;
  v-=0x8000;
  *value = v;
}
```

I can't quite work out what this does.  I assume 'int' in this context is signed 32 bit.  I think 0x8000 would be unsigned 32bit int, and outside the range of a signed 32 bit int. (edit - this is wrong, it is outside of a signed 16 bit int)

I am not sure if one of these would be cast first, and how the casting would handle overflows, and/or how the subtraction would handle the over flow.

I could try on a modern system, but I am also unsure if the results would be the same.

Edit for clarity:

1: 'v-=0x8000;' is straight from the original code, this is what makes little sense to me.  v is defined as an int.

2: I have the code, this is not from asm.

3: The original code is very, very bad.

Edit: I have the answer!  The answer below wasn't quite right, but it got me there (fix up and I'll mark it as the answer).

The data in v is coming from an ambiguous source, which actually seems to be sending *unsigned* 16 bit data, but it is being stored as a signed int.  Latter on in the program all values are converted to floats and normalised to an average 0 point, so actual value doesn't matter, only order.  Because we are looking at an unsigned int as a signed one, values over 32767 are incorrectly placed below 0, so this hack leaves the value as signed, but swaps the negative and positive numbers around (not changing order).  End results is all numbers have the same order (but different values) as if they were unsigned in the first place.

(...and this is not the worst code example in this program)

Comment: Are you sure the code is correct? Surely it should say `*value` instead of `value`.

Comment: You mentioned reverse engineering. Is the code you wrote in C maybe converted from assembler? In assember SUB doesn't only subtract, but also sets cpu flags that are used in conditional jumps. The word size is probably 16bit, so this could be a check for something.

Comment: > Surely it should say *value instead of value - Yep, sorry typed that up quickly, that part isn't the unknown bit.

Comment: This is not converted from asm, I have the original code.  It is worth noting that the original code is *bad* and has many mistakes.

Comment: The line v=-0x8000 is verbatum, and v is an int.

Comment: So the code is `v=-0x8000` **verbatim**? Because that's **very different** from what you've posted in your question. (Your question contains **-=**, and your last comment contains **=-**.)

Comment: Sorry, making mistakes all over the place, the question is correct that comment is not.

Comment: Can you give an example or two of where the function is used?

Comment: @Bruce this is one case where the assembly might be more enlightening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Borland C 3.x, `int` and `short` were the same: 16 bits. `long` was 32-bits.

A hex literal has the first type in which the value can be represented: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int` or `unsigned long int`.

In the case of Borland C, `0x8000` is a decimal value of 32768 and won't fit in an `int`, but will in an `unsigned int`. So `unsigned int` it is.

The statement `v -= 0x8000 ;` is identical to `v = v - 0x8000 ;`

On the right-hand side, the `int` value `v` is implicitly cast to `unsigned int`, per the rules, the arithmetic operation is performed, yielding an `rval` that is an `unsigned int`. That `unsigned int` is then, again per the rules, implicitly cast back to the type of the `lval`.

So, by my estimation, the net effect is to toggle the sign bit — something that could be more easily and clearly done via simple bit-twiddling: `*value ^= 0x8000 ;`.

Comment: @PeterGibson. Fixed it for you. Still won't fit in a 16-bit signed int. Clearly, I haven't had enough coffee today :D

Comment: Thanks, drinking my cup now :) Also doesn't this *toggle* the sign bit rather than clearing it?

Comment: So the negative on 0x8000 has no effect?  I suspect this but can't be sure.  If v is negative this results in a inverted positive (-1=>32767, -32768->0) number (as you describe, clearing the sign bit).  If it is positive in the first place doesn't it do the reverse (make negative and invert).

Comment: I just tested it in Visual C. Coercing things to `short` and `unsigned short`. It does indeed appear toggle the sign bit. Answer amended.

Comment: @PeterGibson Note: `0x8000` is an `unsigned` with a value of 32,768.  `32768` is a `long` with same value.

Answer (score 1):

There is possibly a clue on this page http://www.ousob.com/ng/borcpp/nga0e24.php - Guide to Borland C++ 2.x ( with Turbo C )

> There is no such thing as a negative numeric constant. If
>                   a minus sign precedes a numeric constant it is treated as
>                   the unary minus operator, which, along with the constant,
>                   constitutes a numeric expression.  This is important with
>                   -32768, which, while it can be represented as an int,
>                   actually has type long int, since 32768 has type long. To
>                   get the desired result, you could use (int) -32768,
>                   0x8000, or 0177777.

This implies the use of [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for negative numbers. Interestingly, the two's complement of 0x8000 is 0x8000 itself (as the value +32768 does not fit in the range for signed 2 byte ints).

So what does this mean for your function? Bit wise, this has the effect of toggling the sign bit, here are some examples:

```
f(0) = f(0x0000) = 0x8000 = -32768
f(1) = f(0x0001) = 0x8001 = -32767
f(0x8000) = 0
f(0x7fff) = 0xffff
```

It seems like this could be represented as `val ^= 0x8000`, but perhaps the XOR operator was not implemented in Borland back then?

Comment: That would make sense. `0x8000` is `32768` in decimal. And `0177777` (octal) is `65535` in decimal.

Comment: This really helps, but I am still not sure what the end result is to the int.

Comment: Thanks this is correct, I just saw Nicholas Carey's edit first.

Comment: The XOR operator _was_ implemented in Borland back then.